# Error using installing MSSQL Server2014 using chef

Tags: sql-server, windows, chef-infra

I have window 2012 R2 based two VM machines.
One is using for Chef-workstation and other is for  Chef-client.

I am trying to install MSSQL Server 2014 using chef-cmd from chef-workstation on chef-client.

Sometimes I am getting below error on chef-client while installing MSSQL Server.

> check for instance name, got: 'MSSQLSERVER' Error: Action
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.FinalCalculateSettingsAction"
>   threw an exception during execution.
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException:
>   There was an error generating the XML document. --->
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInfrastructureException:
>   There was an error generating the XML document. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document. --->
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access is denied.
>   at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData,
>   Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Common.SqlSecureString.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) 
>   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteSerializable(IXmlSerializable
>   serializable, String name, String ns, Boolean isNullable, Boolean
>   wrapped)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAgentConfigurationPublic.Write6_AgentConfigurationPublic(String
>   n, String ns, AgentConfigurationPublic o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean
>   needType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAgentConfigurationPublic.Write7_AgentConfigurationPublic(Object
>   o)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()
>   Error: Action
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction"
>   threw an exception during execution.
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException:
>   There was an error generating the XML document. --->
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInfrastructureException:
>   There was an error generating the XML document. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document. --->
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access is denied.
>   at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData,
>   Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Common.SqlSecureString.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)

For more information:
https://discourse.chef.io/t/error-action-microsoft-sqlserver-configuration-setupextension-finalcalculatesettingsaction-threw-an-exception-during-execution/13778

Comment: For more information

Comment: For more information https://discourse.chef.io/t/error-action-microsoft-sqlserver-configuration-setupextension-finalcalculatesettingsaction-threw-an-exception-during-execution/13778